# Uploading to App Store, can't click "Always Allow" in codesign dialog

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, keychain

I want to publish my iPhone application.
I successfully archive the app but can't upload because of codesign dialog issue.

- Archive the app (`Product` -> `Archive`)
- In organizer window, click `Upload to App Store...`
- Click `Upload`
- Then this dialog opens and I can't click neither `Always Allow` nor `Allow`

[image: codesign dialog]

- After clicking `Deny`, Xcode says `An error occurred during upload: codesign failed`

What should I do?
Any helps would be thankful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i solved is problem with

Go to **keychain access** > Select **Login** in keychains and **Certificates** in category

double click or right click on your **certificate**

now set setting from this image

[image]

and now  Select **Login** in keychains and **Keys** in category

double click or right click on your **key**

(for find key of certificate ,expand your certificate then display key and in keys tab expand your key then display your certificate)

now set setting from this image 
[image]

it may be solved your problem if not solved then delete your certificate and reinstall it.

Answer (score 7):

Check your log files for the following message after clicking the allow button:

```
Ignoring user action since the dialog has received events from an untrusted source
```

You most likely have a third party application installed that interfaces with the mouse or keyboard. For instance an application like MagicPrefs would prevent you from clicking the allow button. Disabling the application should solve your problem.

Comment: Very true. Happened to me, using SmoothMouse. I believe this is a better solution than letting all applications access the certificate

Comment: This also happens if you are logging into the machine remotely. In my case, I could not approve this request via Screen Sharing or even locally on the machine while a Screen Sharing session was going on.

Comment: Same problem here, unfortunately I killed the app thinking it was stuck, and I can not, for the life of me, bring back the dialog the had "Always Allow". I uninstalled the app (VPN), remove its settings, removed its logins in Keychain, even tried to change the Access Control on them to "Allow All Apps", without success.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Apple's forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25092), utilites for mouse (such as MagicPrefs, smoothMouth, etc...) or VPNs might bring this problem.

I had use MagicPrefs and encountered this problem after upgraded to OS X 10.11.
And I uninstalled MagicPrefs, both "Allow" and "Always Allow" buttons can be clicked.

Comment: Did you find a solution for VPN?